# Jenkins Kubernetes - Use custom Agent pod spec from the Controller pod

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, kubernetes-helm, jenkins-kubernetes, jcasc

I have deployed a Jenkins instance in a Kubernetes cluster using [this helm chart](https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts). Inside the instance, several declarative pipelines are configured as JCasC. These pipelines need a custom agent pod with several containers. At the moment the yaml spec, let's call them `jenkins.pod.yaml`, are declared in the repositories that host the application code, where the Jenkinsfile also is, where i fetch them easily like this.

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      yamlFile 'jenkins.pod.yaml'
      retries 2
    }
  }
...
  stages {
    stage('Build war') {
      steps {
        container('builder') {
          sh 'some command in the 'builder' container'
        }
      }
    }
...
```

This is not ideal since the `jenkins.pod.yaml` files contain strings that can vary by branch, such as the container registry name, and it would be error prone to have to edit that in the code repo.

My idea was to install the `jenkins.pod.yaml`s in the jenkins controller pod, properly templated, and fetch them with a label from the Jenkinsfile. There is indeed a `agent.podTemplate` value in the helm chart that seems to allow configuring a custom agent pod spec, but i could not fetch it in the Jenkinsfile, resulting in either errors or the standard `jnlp` image being used.

I've tried setting `agent.podTemplates` in the chart to my custom template

```
agent:
  podTemplates:
   custom-jenkins-label: |
     - name: python
       label: custom-jenkins-label
       serviceAccount: jenkins
       containers:
...
```

and changing the Jenkinsfile as

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    label 'custom-jenkins-label'
  }
...
```

from other answers on this website, but to no avail.
An alternative would be to mount these `jenkins.pod.yaml` agent pod spec files into a volume in the jenkins controller pod, but this also does not seem to work using the `controller.volumes/mount` helm chart values. The agent does not see these files.

Has anyone solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
It was all good except the `podTemplate` section has a very weird syntax, so I was providing the wrong pod template.
I recommend using hte `podTemplate.yaml` field and specifying a standard kubernetes pod template there.

```yaml
  podTemplates:
    my-agent: |
      - name: my-agent
        label: my-agent
        namespace: pipeline
        yaml: |-
          apiVersion: v1
          kind: Pod
          spec:
...
```